# Default screenshots in App Store iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I've got an app in App Store for a while.
Recently I've noticed that by default iPad preview images are displayed when I visit App Store with browser.
I would like to make the default to be the iPhone look, because first of all my app is an "iPhone app".

Is there a configuration in Xcode project or App Store Connect were I can set/force iPhone to be the default ?

Web link of App Store Connect.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/zalgo/id1191945249

The screenshot of the problem
[image]

P.S. I've been rubbing my butt against this issue already half a day, cannot find any solution.
Has anybody communicated on this with App Store customer support ?

Comment: i've gotta say, "rubbing my butt against this issue" is my new favorite expression. i've adopted this into many recent conversations and i just had to come in here to pay respects to where i first learned the phrase!

Comment: @Mr.T this is one of the best compliments I've received from SO community ! Hats off comrade

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lengthy discussions with App Store Connect support, finally the problem is resolved

The “Designed for …” badge appears automatically
for iPhone and iPad apps that are made available for Apple silicon Macs.

With that option iPad screenshots will be displayed automatically when navigating to products URL with web-browser.

If you have selected “App Silicon Mac Availability” in the Pricing and Availability section of App Store Connect.
Uncheck it and check the product page URL after 24 hours have passed.

[image]

Comment: after unchecking, will the iphone screenshots be the default?

Comment: @Augustus yes, exactly

Comment: Worked exactly, iphone screenshots became default in an hour of change.

Comment: what else does this option do other than changing defaults screenshots to iPhones? App should still be able to run on Silicon Macs right?